# Not showing marker on map

Tags: android, google-maps

I want get the current location of user on map
when I run the app ,app is successfully launched it takes the permission from user to take location of user through GPS but marker is not showing on map.

when i run the this app on emulator it shows some where else location and when i run this app on mobile it does not show location(marker) 
her is the code .

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    LocationListener locationListener;

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode ==1) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                Log.i("Location::::::", location.toString());
                LatLng person = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
                mMap.clear();
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(person).title("person").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE)));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(person, 15));

            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

            }
        };
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23){
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,0 ,locationListener);
        }
        else {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
            } else {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
                Location lastLoc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                LatLng loc = new LatLng(lastLoc.getLatitude(), lastLoc.getLongitude());
                mMap.clear();
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(loc).title("person").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE)));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(loc, 15));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> when i run the this app on emulator it shows some where else location

It's not showing your current location because when using the emulator, it's location is set in the settings, it doesn't determine your actual location, so basically it's set manually.

> when i run this app on mobile it does not show location(marker)

Regarding that, you can try calling `addMarker` in `onMapReady` directly first. And moving your `onLocationChanged` callback outside of the `onMapReady`.